# My program crashes due to SIGABRT?

Tags: uiimageview, sigabrt

```
    2012-05-31 00:17:51.384 SAMPLEGAME[2901:10703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<SAMPLEGAMEViewController 0x752c140> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key girlHeadView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1460022 0x1a7dcd6 0x145fee1 0xe47022 0xdb8f6b 0xdb8edb 0xdd3d50 0x6bb71a 0x1461dea 0x13cb7f1 0x6ba26e 0x5601fc 0x560779 0x56099b 0x4bf401 0x4bf670 0x4bf836 0x4c672a 0x497596 0x498274 0x4a7183 0x4a7c38 0x49b634 0x3aa1ef5 0x1434195 0x1398ff2 0x13978da 0x1396d84 0x1396c9b 0x497c65 0x499626 0x21fd 0x2165)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Hi everyone,

I am new to iOS programming and am lost on something.
I renamed my original UIIMAGEVIEW from "yelOrb"... which was inefficient for the real object in the end replacing a yellow orb. So I renamed it to "girlHeadView". (Mind you, this is what I named the UIImageView that you control with arrow keys.)

Now whenever I run the program I get a stink in' SIGABRT telling me this [in the code above].
I even renamed "girlHeadView" back to "yelOrb".

I went through my .h & .m file, no stray word or incorrect spelling is causing this.

How am I able to fix this? I just implemented a button function to change the UIImageView (I even commented it all out to see if that caused it- still SIGABRT issue) and I can't even run the simulator.

Thank you!

Edit: Found my problem, I had to remove and re-add the yelOrb's image on the storyboard. Odd, but it worked. :)

Comment: Consider adding an answer with your solution, and answering it, so this question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there's an outlet in interface builder connecting the UIImageView to the old property name, `yelOrb`. Then, when the view controller's view loads, it tries to make that connection to `yelOrb` which no longer exists, so you get that error.

Comment: Thank you much. I just figured out how to log back in, so I greatly appreciate your service mrb. :)